# Random Dips/Pits in Elevation surface in ArcGlobe 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcgis-10.2, arcglobe

I have an elevation raster which I load into ArcGlobe as an elevation source and appears to have large pits and dips in it when I place floating features such as roads and imagery.

The odd thing is that the phenomenon does not show up in ArcScene and if I import the raster into a FGDB the pits disappear.

[image]

It's seriously looking like Apple Maps and any help would be nice.